# Jquery on-click method parameters comma not supported

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I got dynamic `onclick` with 2 parameters (id and name).

Sample data

```
id   name
1    foo bar 
2    hi foo's, where is bar
3    hello foo
```

js code

```
// django for loop
{% for original in data %}
    <button onclick="click_new('{{original.id}}', '{{original.level_name}}')">Click New</button>
{% endfor %}


function click_new(id, name){
   alert(name)
}
```

**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input**

for `hi foo's, where is bar`

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/32wzcr4k/

Comment: Look at the HTML output. Most likely there is a mismatch with the single/double quotes in the output.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan question updated please check

Comment: Look at the syntax highlighting and error displayed on that line, what does it say? You'll see that the `&#39;` is converted back to a `'` which ends the `onclick` attribute early, causing the syntax error.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan please see this https://jsfiddle.net/32wzcr4k/

Comment: You can see the issue there in jsFiddles own syntax highlighting. You need to make sure that the double/single quotes you use are consistent, encapsulate the entire value, and that any quotes within the content you inject are escaped so that they do not interfere with the quotes in the HTML/JS.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan data is dynamic can't predict. need solution

Comment: Exactly, escape the quotes in the dynamic server side value as you inject it in to the HTML. Instead of using `&#39;` use ```\```, for example: `foo\'s emotions...`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230258/discussion-between-c-grey-and-rory-mccrossan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternate solution would be setting second value as  data-attribute and inside function pass `this` to identify button which is clicked .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
function click_new(id, el) {
  alert($(el).data("name") +" -- "+id)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--<button data-name="{{original.level_name}}" onclick="click_new('{{original.id}}',this)">Click New</button>-->
<button data-name="foo's, where is bar" onclick="click_new('1',this )">Click New</button>
<button data-name="foo" onclick="click_new('2',this )">Click New</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

Hi looks like your function is messing with a single quote and double quote.

your HTML should be something like this.

```
<button type='button' onclick="click_me(1,'hi foo\'s where is bar')">
11
</button>
```

here is working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Negirox/j1nf8c7a/2/)

Comment: @c.grey have you checked fiddle?

Comment: @c.grey updated. its all about parameter i just misinterpreted the question.